# Xorg crashing in custom image

Tags: driver, embedded-linux, xorg

I generated an image to an [advantech PCM-9375](https://advdownload.advantech.com/productfile/PIS/PCM-9375%20A3/file/PCM-9375-A3_DS(113021)20211130143808.pdf) board using the yocto system (branch dunfell).

The outcome uses Xorg as the video manager, however, the application is crashing due to the geode driver installed with it.

I debugged it and discovered that the crashes happen when the driver function LXReadMSR is called with the parameters: addr=0x80002000h, lo=0xbffff994 and hi=0xbffff998. The last two are pointers, and their contents are: 5136 and 0, respectively.
The snippet below is the gdb's backtrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb7693ba7 in LXReadMSR (hi=0xbffff998, lo=0xbffff994, addr=2147491840) at ../../xf86-video-geode-2.11.20/src/lx_driver.c:131
#1  LXReadMSR (addr=2147491840, lo=0xbffff994, hi=0xbffff998) at ../../xf86-video-geode-2.11.20/src/lx_driver.c:126
#2  0xb7681eef in msr_create_geodelink_table (gliu_nodes=0xb76b2880 <gliu_nodes>) at ../../xf86-video-geode-2.11.20/src/cim/cim_msr.c:199
#3  0xb7682400 in msr_init_table () at ../../xf86-video-geode-2.11.20/src/cim/cim_msr.c:82
#4  0xb7693282 in LXPreInit (pScrni=0x6a79e0, flags=0) at ../../xf86-video-geode-2.11.20/src/lx_driver.c:349
#5  0x00480986 in InitOutput (pScreenInfo=0x688280 <screenInfo>, argc=12, argv=0xbffffc44) at ../../../../xorg-server-1.20.14/hw/xfree86/common/xf86Init.c:522
#6  0x00444525 in dix_main (argc=12, argv=0xbffffc44, envp=0xbffffc78) at ../../xorg-server-1.20.14/dix/main.c:193
#7  0x0042d89b in main (argc=12, argv=0xbffffc44, envp=0xbffffc78) at ../../xorg-server-1.20.14/dix/stubmain.c:34
```

Looking in the [documentation of the processor](https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/33234H_LX_databook.pdf), I found out that addr points to GLD_MSR_CAP register (chapter "6.6.1.1 GLD Capabilities MSR (GLD_MSR_CAP)" in the documentation), however I didn't figure out what's happening.

Solutions tried:

- Insertion of the CLI kernel instruction "iomem=relaxed", as pointed by item 6 of the driver's readme file in its [github repository](https://github.com/freedesktop/xorg-xf86-video-geode);
- Replacing of the kernel configuration "CONFIG_BLK_DEV_CS5535=y" by "CONFIG_BLK_DEV_CS5536=y".

None of them worked.

**Xorg version: 1.20.14**

**Geode driver version: 2.11.20**

Did anyone have a similar problem? Does anyone know what's happenning?

My next tries will be the modification of kernel config parameters, but there are a lot and I'don't know which of them are related to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved when the kernel option "CONFIG_X86_IOPL_IOPERM" was enabled.

I've come to this solution after reading [this post](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/inline-assembly-causing-seg-fault-in-amd-geode-driver-555095/).